# Why Sql type provider very slow?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I have the following code. It will take a minutes if I change the line `where (row.SiteID = 1)` to `where (row.SiteID = 2)`. I searched on web and added `LocalSchemaFile = "Schema.dbml", ForceUpdate = false` for `SqlDataConnection`. It still takes about 15 seconds everytime when the query condition is changed.

**Update:**
If I rerun the code without changing the Linq code, it will get and print the row from the database table instantly.

```
open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq
open System.Net
open System.IO
open FSharp.Data

type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=Svr;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"> 
//, LocalSchemaFile = "Schema.dbml", ForceUpdate = false > // Still take 15 secs
let getARow =
    let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
    db.DataContext.Log <- System.Console.Out
    let query = query { 
        for row in db.Table1 do 
        where (row.SiteID = 1) 
        select (Some(row.Col1, row.Col2))
        headOrDefault
        }
    query 

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let aRow = getARow
    printfn "%A" aRow 
    0
```

Comment: just to clarify: it takes 15 seconds to do what?

Comment: @desco It takes 15 seconds to `printfn "%A" aRow`.

Comment: so query execution takes 15 seconds. At glance it looks like something that happens on database side and has nothing in common with type providers. Do you have the same results if you call your database from  C# or run query using Sql Management Studio?

Comment: The query seems simple enough.  One trivial thing you might check is that `SiteID` is an indexed column.  How many rows are present in `Table1`?

Comment: @desco If I rerun the code without changing the Linq code, it will get and print the row from the database table instantly.

Comment: @Shredderroy The table has only two rows. It should be the data provider issue. I've updated the question.

Comment: I see [telepathy mode=on] first time you hit F5 - the code is compiled (and during compilation type provider queries database to fetch the schema) and executed. Next time you press F5 (assuming that nothing was changed in the source file) the code will executed without recompilation [telepathy mode=off].

Comment: @desco Where to set `telepathy mode`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried outputting a timestamp at the start of the main function? Is it possible you're seeing compile time, and not run time? If you don't change the code and hit F5, it will just run the already-compiled version. If you tweak the code, when you press F5 it will need to recompile (and compiling F# seems pretty slow).

If you output a timestamp at the start of the program and after the data access, it's possible you'll see that the runtime is just as fast in both cases.

Comment: yes, I think it takes a while to compile after the code is changed.